# Angular 6, SonarQube: src folder not ignored while checking package.json

Tags: angular, sonarqube

I’m using SonarQube (Version 6.7.5) for my Angular 6 Project and want to deal with the following code smell:

> “Module ‘src’ is not listed as dependency in package.json”

There are many imports throughout the project like “import … from ‘src/app/…’;”
I added the following rule to my tslint.json:

```
“no-implicit-dependencies”: [true, [“src”, “app”]]
```

but no success.
How can I best solve this code smell?

Comment: Is just ignoring it an option? I would argue the code quality does not increase when you somehow work around it.

Comment: Normally, you would use a relative path for the import, e.g. `import … from './…'`

Answer (score 0):

As Henry said. Use relative paths. I changed from `src/...` starting absolute paths to relative paths and it fixed it.

I'm using Angular 6 also.